# Creating reference with tables

Tags: postgresql, reference

I have two tables that already have data in them and i would like to create reference via postgressql OR SQL shell. The reference should be like this:

[IMG][http://i.imgur.com/SMUEo4r.png[/IMG]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWSom.png)

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please don't post screen shots like that. Add the DDL script that you used to create the tables. It's easier for us to see the real table structure then. Plus the code is kept with the question. The screen shot might be gone someday and then your question doesn't make sense any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table statusi
   add constraint fk_darbinieki_statusi
   foreign key (id_darbinieks) references darbinieki (id_darbinieks);
```

Note that I used **un**quoted identifiers which are case **in**sensitive.

Given your screenshot it might be that you created quoted identifiers using double quotes which are case **sensitive**. `"ID_statusi"`  is a different name than `ID_statusi`. So maybe you need to use double quotes when running the above statement. In general, using double quotes for identifiers is not such a good idea. It creates more trouble than it's worth.

More details in the manual:

- defining foreign keys:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK
- Rules for identifiers:
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS
- ALTER TABLE: 
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html